# How to secure webpages when user is not logged in

Tags: java, security, jsf

I have some XHTML pages. When I run the project, I can view the page even if I am not logged in. When I type directly in the adress bar, I can access to the page.

How can I protect my XHTML files except the `login.xhtml`? I tried to add a security constraint to FacesConfig but it blocks all my `*.xhtml` even the `login.xhtml`.

---

**Update**

I added this on my web.xml file

```
 <security-constraint>
     <display-name>Protection</display-name>
     <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>Protection</web-resource-name>
         <description>Protection</description>
         <url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>
     </web-resource-collection>
 </security-constraint>
```

I put all my files expect `login.xhtml` in the `/secure` folder.

But when I run the project, I can always access when I type `.../secured/*.jsf` in adressbar. How can I protect it when I am browsing offline or not logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I tried to add a security constraint to FacesConfig but it blocks all my `*.xhtml` even the `login.xhtml`*

The `faces-config.xml` has no notion of security constraints. Probably you're confusing with `web.xml`. You need to make the `url-pattern` of the security constraint more specific. Don't use `*.xhtml`, but use `/secured/*` or so and put the restricted files in that folder (expect of the `login.xhtml` file of course).

Besides that, you may want to instruct the browser to *not* cache those pages. You can achieve this by a `Filter` which is mapped on the same `url-pattern` and does the following in the `doFilter()` method:

```
HttpServletResponse hsr = (HttpServletResponse) response;
hsr.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
hsr.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
hsr.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

With this, the enduser won't be able to view the page from the browser cache. Don't forget to clear the browser cache before testing.

Comment: Yeah sorry ! I would mean web.xml .

Comment: You're welcome. You by the way don't need to yell like that, I as being a deaf born really won't ever hear that.

Comment: I don't think it was the cache... even  when I clear, I can access... And where I can put this code "HttpServet...". And where I put the Filter too ?

Comment: Probably there's a typo in url-pattern of your security constraint or you didn't restart the server after editing `web.xml`? As to the filter, just implement `javax.servlet.Filter`, put exactly this code in the `doFilter()` method and map the filter in `web.xml`.

Comment: Even if I restart the server, I can access. 
Sorry, but i don't use servlet... I use hum, jsf ? controller ? managed bean ? I use an interface and an implementation. And finally, I use an controller. So in which file do I implement javax.servlet.Filter Please ?

Can use Session for protected pages ? Because I run a session when connected in login.xhtml

Comment: JSF runs on top of Servlet API. You can just create and use Filters the usual way. As to the access problem, big chance that your `web.xml` declaration is invalid. Either the url-pattern did actually not match, or there is no authorization constraint. Hard to tell without more detail about the configuration.